# Parsing a dynamic webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape an image from Amazon and it is not easy.

I think I am almost there, but I am failing to get the result.

Here, I am using selenium to 1. open the main images and 2. click the second image among the thumbnales
3. and then to get the src of the full size of the second image.

but it fails and I don't know why

this is the lines that I wrote.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.amazon.com/Kraft-Original-Macaroni-Microwaveable-Packets/dp/B005ECO3H0"
driver.get(url)
action = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#landingImage').click()
time.sleep(10)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ivImage_1').click()
amazon = soup.select_one(".fullscreen")
imgUrl = amazon.find("img")['src']
print(imgUrl)
```

One thing that I cannot understand is, if I type print(amazon), it gives me the img tag, but according to the result of the code above, imgUrl is 'Nonetype'.

Please help me to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.amazon.com/Kraft-Original-Macaroni-Microwaveable- 
Packets/dp/B005ECO3H0"
driver.get(url)
action = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#landingImage').click()
time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ivImage_1').click()
image_url = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fullscreen").get_attribute("src")
print(image_url)

#if you want to download
import requests
resp = requests.get(image_url)
with open("asd.png", "wb")as image:
    image.write(resp.content)
```